# How to safe print an external HTML inside a page? iFrame?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm making an API Test Tool which makes requests to external urls.

Most of these external urls return a JSON, but sometimes a HTML can be return as well, in these cases I would like to show the rendered HTMl.

My first solution was to render the returned HTML inside an iFrame.

```
<script id="response-body-content" type="application/vnd.response-body">
  <%= raw response_body.gsub("script", "xcriptx") %>
</script>

<iframe id="response-body-preview"></iframe>
<script>
  $(function(){
    var ifrm = document.getElementById("response-body-preview");
    var ifrmDocument;
    if(ifrm.contentWindow) {
      ifrmDocument = ifrm.contentWindow.document
      } else {
      ifrmDocument = ifrm.contentDocument
    }
    ifrmDocument.open()
    ifrmDocument.write($("#response-body-content").text().replace(/xcriptx/g, "script"));
    ifrmDocument.close()
  });
</script>
```

I had to replace `script` to `*xscript*` to prevent the external HTML to break the my script tag container `#response-body-content` then to print in the iFrame I have to replace it back.

Is there any other workaround to print/render (safe) external HTML inside a page?

Comment: Will the HTML being returned always just be HTML or can it contain CSS and JS within the head?

Comment: The returned HTML can contain CSS and JS. It is also a problem in case they use relative path, since they are in other domain.